# Could not connect to host 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Tags: linux, firewall, slackware

I am getting the below error message

> Could not connect to host 127.0.0.1: Connection refused.

on `ktorrent` on `slackware 13.1` and the torrents cannot start.

I tried to reconfigure the `ktorrent` prefernces, I flushed the `iptables` but still no success.

When I log in via `root` and start `ktorrent`, then the torrents start and no error message is displayed, but when I am logged in as a regular user then the torrents don't work.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is there any details on which port it tries to connect on your localhost?  Is it below 1024 (reserved for superuser)?

Comment: No it's not below 1024.

Comment: @muteto output of `iptables -L -nv`? also do you have a session of ktorrent running as root? or any other user concurrently?

Comment: It doesn't show any rule, like i said i flushed the iptables, and no, i don't have a session of ktorrent running as root.

Answer (score 1):

After you started it with root, it changed permissions of some files and temporary folders. After that, it's not possible to start it with normal user anymore.

You can try reinstalling it, or running for example

```
strace ktorrent
```

to get error messages. Also, you should check ktorrent logs.